# I want to remove the bellow string: what should I do

Tags: python-3.6

```
['Invoice No.\nPage  1\nWS350430\nDRDR30899']
['INVOICE :\nInvoice Date:\nPage \nSI01240784']
```

I want to remove the below strings: what should I do?

\nPage  1\nWS350430\
\nInvoice Date:\nPage \n

These strings come from a pdf by using regex.

Comment: As a hint, check out the `split` method defined on strings.

Comment: how can we do it here ...i am not getting correct thing....may you please write it here i tired                                                                                                       
>>> x=str(['INVOICE :\nInvoice Date:\nPage \nSI01240784'])
>>> x.split("\n")
["['INVOICE :\\nInvoice Date:\\nPage \\nSI01240784']"]